# R: extract hour from variable format timestamp

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My dataframe has timestamp with and without seconds, and a random use of 0 in front of months and hours, i.e. 01 or 1

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(cust=c('A','A','B','B'), timestamp=c('5/31/2016 1:03:12', '05/25/2016 01:06',
                                           '6/16/2016  01:03', '12/30/2015 23:04:25'))
cust     timestamp
 A      5/31/2016 1:03:12
 A      05/25/2016 01:06
 B      6/16/2016  01:03
 B      12/30/2015 23:04:25
```

How to extract hours into a separate column? The desired output:

```
 cust     timestamp            hours
 A      5/31/2016 1:03:12       1
 A      05/25/2016 01:06        1
 B      6/16/2016  9:03         9
 B      12/30/2015 23:04:25    23
```

I prefer the answer with tidyverse and mutate, but my attempt fails to extract hours correctly:

```
df %>% mutate(hours=strptime(timestamp, '%H') %>% as.character() )

# A tibble: 4 × 3
   cust           timestamp               hours
  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>
1     A   5/31/2016 1:03:12 2016-10-31 05:00:00
2     A    05/25/2016 01:06 2016-10-31 05:00:00
3     B    6/16/2016  01:03 2016-10-31 06:00:00
4     B 12/30/2015 23:04:25 2016-10-31 12:00:00
```

Comment: Have you tried converting "timestamp" to a date-time before trying to extract hours?  Seems like `as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` might do the trick for you if you don't need the seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(cust=c('A','A','B','B'), timestamp=c('5/31/2016 1:03:12', '05/25/2016 01:06',
                                                      '6/16/2016  09:03', '12/30/2015 23:04:25'))
df %>% mutate(hours=hour(strptime(timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')) %>% as.character() )

cust           timestamp   hours
1    A   5/31/2016 1:03:12     1
2    A    05/25/2016 01:06     1
3    B    6/16/2016  09:03     9
4    B 12/30/2015 23:04:25    23
```

Comment: Beautiful, @sandipan!To convert hours to integers, works as well: df %>% mutate(hours=hour(strptime(timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')) %>% as.integer() )

Comment: Thanks pal @Irakli

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that appends `00` for the seconds when they are missing, then converts to a date using `lubridate` and extracts the hours using `format`. Note, if you don't want the `00:00` at the end of the hours, you can just eliminate them from the output format in `format`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    cleanTime = ifelse(grepl(":[0-9][0-9]:", timestamp)
                       , timestamp
                       , paste0(timestamp, ":00")) %>% mdy_hms
    , hour = format(cleanTime, "%H:00:00")
    )
```

returns:

```
   cust           timestamp           cleanTime     hour
  <chr>               <chr>              <dttm>    <chr>
1     A   5/31/2016 1:03:12 2016-05-31 01:03:12 01:00:00
2     A    05/25/2016 01:06 2016-05-25 01:06:00 01:00:00
3     B    6/16/2016  01:03 2016-06-16 01:03:00 01:00:00
4     B 12/30/2015 23:04:25 2015-12-30 23:04:25 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp is a character string (), you need to format is as a date (with `as.Date` for example) before you can start using functions like `strptime`.

You are going to have to go through some string manipulations to have properly formatted data before you can convert it to dates. Prepend a zero to months with a single digit and append `:00` to hours with missing seconds. Use `strsplit()` and other regex functions. Afterwards do `as.Date(df$timestamp,format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')`, then you will be able to use `strptime` to extract the hours.